# Send email using gMail without revealing IP address

Tags: email, smtp, ip, anonymous

I'd like the backend IP address of my server to remain confidential as protection against DDOS attacks.

I'd like to use gMail to send any automated mails but gMail will reveal my backend IP address in the mail headers if I use their smtp service.

Does anyone know of any methods or tools that I can use to send emails through gmail without using smtp.

In other words, I need to simulate a human gMail user using http.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: FWIW, a human GMail user will also have their machine's IP logged when sending via SMTP, so I'm not sure that makes any sense. That said, there is no other way to send email via GMail - it's SMTP or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

GMail does not support sending email via any other means than SMTP.